# Can I use a progress indicator without using threads and asynchronous tasks?

Tags: android

If yes, how we can achieve this?

Comment: You can but it generally is not a good idea. Why are you avoiding Threads and Asyncs?

Comment: Please consider adding a few hundred words explaining the actual problem you are trying to solve.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Theoretically speaking, yes, you can, but you should not. Because progress indicator is meant for a relatively long-running task, and if you try to do this on your UI thread, your application will get force closed as non-responsive.